# How to get the module in order to write a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing my first custom directive that will perform form validation in different way. I'd like to re-use this directive in many different project, but I don't know how to get the module.

When declaring a directive, you do this:

```
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
    .directive("validation", function () {
        return {
            // etc...
        }
    });
```

but the "exampleApp" is hard-coded. How do I declare a directive when I don't know the name of the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to get a handle of your defined module. Here you can get reference of `exampleModule` as below:

```
angular.module("exampleApp", []) // This will create new module as you've written [] i.e injector
    .directive("validation", function () {
        return {
            // etc...
        }
    });

  angular.module("exampleApp").directive(...) // It will search for existing exampleApp and gives you the reference of that module so that you can define directive in that module.
```

**To use it as Third party module**

Create seperate angular module with this directive and just inject that module to your app. It will work directly. You don't need to define it for that module.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Every directive must have a module. If it is a utility module you will reuse then name it as such. In the application where you wish to use the directive simply declare a dependency on your utility module and it will just work.

Comment: Yes, but when declaring my module as above, what do I user for the "exampleApp" module name? It could be anything!

Comment: Oh I got you. I was misreading the module directive declaration. I though the "exampleApp" was the name of the module that was using the directive. Silly me.